# Making an alarm clock, why is my Calendar null?

Tags: android, android-studio, alarm, android-calendar, android-timepicker

This summer, in order to learn app development, I have decided to make an alarm clock in Android Studio without much prior knowledge of Java or OOP.

I am trying to get the user's input for the alarm using TimePickerDiaglog, then store that time inside the Calendar utility-thing, so I can set a pending intent with the Alarm Manager.

```
public class AlarmParameters extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText time;
    Button btn_set_alarm;
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    Calendar mcurrentTime;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pending_intent;
    private AlarmReceiver alarm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_parameters);

        //match ids
        btn_set_alarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.parameters_btn_set_alarm);
        time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time_box_text);

        //remove pesky keyboard
        time.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        // perform click event listener on edit text
        time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //retrieve current time
                final Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AlarmParameters.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                        //adds the 0, like : 10:6 AM --> 10:06 AM
                        if(selectedMinute<10){
                            time.setText(selectedHour + ":0" + selectedMinute);
                        }
                        else {
                            time.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                        }

                        //store time picked in the calendar
                        mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
                        mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);

                        // no seconds in the calendar
                        mcurrentTime.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    }
                }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time

                //more settings for dialog window
                mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                mTimePicker.show();
            }
        });

        //actions when you hit the set alarm text
        btn_set_alarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //get the time of the alarm set from text box
                String alarm_set_string = String.valueOf(time.getText());

                //add that alarm to list of alarms on first page
                MainActivity.ALARMARRAY.add(alarm_set_string);

                //create intent to send to alarmReceiver
                final Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmParameters.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

                //set up alarm manager
                alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                //make the myIntent a pending intent?
                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmParameters.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                //tell alarmManager to send the pending intent at the time selected by the timepicker (in calendar now)
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mcurrentTime.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent);//error here

                Log.e("BUTTON", "alarm set");
                finish();
            }
        });
    }}
```

Sadly I receive a NullPointerException, meaning that my Calendar was not set correctly and is null when I use with the AlarmManager?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis()' on a null object reference
                                                                                at xxxxxx.englishalarmclock.AlarmParameters$2.onClick(AlarmParameters.java:95)
```

So I'm thinking that the issue comes down to where I say this inside of the TimePickerDialog.

```
//store time picked in the calendar
mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
mcurrentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
```

I tried doing this, setting the Calendar, inside the btn_set_alarm.setOnclickListener... but I could not figure out how to use the int selectedHour/Minute (arguments for onTimeSet()) when outside of the TimePickerDialog-thing. When I tried setting a public variable of selectedHour/Minute within onTimeSet(), it said it was not allowed.

So, ultimately I have 3 questions:

**1. Why does my Calendar not receive the selectedHour/Minute values when I set them inside onTimeSet()?**

**2. Why am I "not allowed" to set a public variable in onTimeSet()?**

**3. How would I use the selectedHour/Minute variables outside of onTimeSet()?**

Thank you for your time!

--also if you see anything else I'm doing wrong or that I could do better, please tell me! I'm here to learn! \ (•◡•) /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redeclare the mCurrentTime. Just remove the `final Calendar` at line `final Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();`

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sadly, now I get another error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.Calendar.get(int)' on a null object reference` For some reason it thinks the calendar is still null even though it just got the Instance?

Comment: Edit your code in the post please, and tell me which line is linked with this error.

Comment: Nevermind! I made an error when I was editing my code. It works now! Thank you very much!